# Too many buttons in a mobile Navigation Bar

Tags: mobile, navigation

I have an app where people can browse places. I have two screens: a list and a map.

In the navigation bar, I have a back button, a search bar, and a button to switch between the "Map" view and the "List[image]

Now, my problem is, I want to give the user the option to "reset" their search some way. For example, if they search for "Movie Theater" and decide against that search term, I want to be able to go back to viewing all places without having to press "Back" and return to this screen.

Any ideas how I can do this? Obviously I could add another button to the navigation bar but I think that will make it too cluttered. Thanks!

Comment: How does a user actually trigger the search right now?

Comment: Also, what value does the search bar have being constantly exposed? I'd consider looking at how some of the existing mapping apps do this...Google Maps, Apple Maps, Yelp, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my suggestion, a little bit interaction could make it perfect!

[image]

You can make the bar much more clear by adding flat icons to it. As suggested before you can also checkout popular examples of it

Comment: I think this is the way to go. Provide a Search button that shows the search field when the user wants it.

Answer (score 0):

Many mobile search fields (and even desktop fields) have a "x" in the field when it has focus. This would clear the field, serving as your your "reset".

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgjsId.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Many map apps also have an icon which resets any changes to the map and centers the map back on the user's current location.

[image]

If this notion fits with your use case, that is an option. Alternatively, a similar action could be used as an overlay.